# Is there a way to jump directly to vertex/edge or face mode in blender standard keymap?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I tried the first solution here:

[Hotkey to go DIRECTLY to vertex, edge, face edit mode?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129160/hotkey-to-go-directly-to-vertex-edge-face-edit-mode)

But it still doesn't go directly to the desired edit mode (vertex, edge or face) because is stores the last component so if I press "1" to go from object to vertex then go back to object mode then I press "2" for edges it goes back to vertex and I have to press "2" once again for edges.

Is there any way to fix this without implementing a script?